# getInitialProps is not sending data to the page component when wanting to fetch initial data and later update it with a button

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have a component at `app\page.tsx` in Next.js v13.4.12, containing a button.  When I click on it, I want it to call the `handleClick` func.

But the function `getInitialProps` is not called and doesn't send props to the Page component, what should I do?

In fact, I want when the page render for the first time, even if we are not clicking on the button, data render on the page.

```js
'use client'
import { useState } from 'React';

export default function Page({ initialData }) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const req = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=male&results=100');
        const newData = await req.json();

        return setData(newData.results);
    };

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetchData();
    };

    return (
        <Layout>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>FETCH DATA</button>
            {data.map((user) => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        {user.email}
                        <img src={user.picture.medium} alt="" />
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </Layout>
    );
}

Page.getInitialProps = async () => {
    const req = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=female&results=10');
    const data = await req.json();
    return { initialData: data.results };
};
```

Comment: Can you use `getServerSideProps` for this?

Comment: i used getServerSideProps but it not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods like [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) and [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props) are for fetching data on the server but they only work for page components inside the `pages` folder (the initial way of setting up routes in Next.js).

Since Next.js 13, in the `app` directory, we have [Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#server-components), where you can fetch data directly in the component body, where what you want to achieve would be done as below (notice the additional file created):

```
// app/page.js 

import Users from "./users";

export default async function Page() {
  const req = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=female&results=10");
  const data = await req.json();

  return <Users initialUsers={data.results} />;
}
```

You need the below additional component because you need client interactivities (an `onClick` handler here), which you cannot have in the server `Page` component above.

```
// app/users.js 

"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Users({ initialUsers }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialUsers);

  const handleClick = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const req = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=male&results=100");
    const newData = await req.json();
    setData(newData.results);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>FETCH DATA</button>
      {data.map((user, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            {user.email}
            <img src={user.picture.medium} alt="" />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Otherwise, because your page is already a client component with `"use client"` at the top, you could simply use an `useEffect` to load the initial data, like so:

```
// app/page.js 

"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Page() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const req = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=male&results=100");
    const newData = await req.json();
    setData(newData.results);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=female&results=10")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data.results);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>FETCH DATA</button>
      {data.map((user, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            {user.email}
            <img src={user.picture.medium} alt="" />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getInitialProps` is now a legacy API and the documentation recommends using `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps`. But since both are not supported in app router, try this instead:

Create a server component as a parent where you fetch the initial data and then pass it to the client component where all the client-side operations can be handled.

Server Component

```
export async function ServerComponent() {
    const req = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=female&results=10');
    const data = await req.json();

    return (
        <ClientComponent initialData={data.results} />
    )

}
```

Client Component

```
"use client";

export function ClientComponent({ initialData }) {
const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const req = await fetch(
      "https://randomuser.me/api/?gender=male&results=100"
    );
    const newData = await req.json();

    return setData(newData.results);
  };

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetchData();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>FETCH DATA</button>
      {data.map((user) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {user.email}
            <img src={user.picture.medium} alt="" />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```